# Changing variable name as I add it (VS, .NET4, C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, variables

I'm working on a program and I had this problem:

when I add a button, for example, it's called automaticly button1, button2, etc.

I want the posibility to name it as I want it to be called right when I add it without the need of changing the 'Name' in the properties. Like you add a new Form and can name it as I you want, like that just for button, textboxes, etc.

Thanks

Comment: The designer does not work this way.  You can either use the designer as-is - or you can write an extension to VS to make it operate in the manner you would like.

Comment: How do I make an extension?

Comment: Carefully. I'm not a Tutorials-R-Us.  Do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Visual Studio 2010 Visualization and Modeling SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23025). It answers your need, here is Microsoft introduction to it on MSDN

> Domain Specific Languages (DSL Tools) and Architecture Tools SDK for Microsoft > Visual Studio 2010. This SDK provides tools and templates for building Visual > Studio Domain Specific Language designers for Visual Studio 2010 and extending > UML and Layer designers. By using this SDK, **you can build your own graphical** 
>   **or form-based designers for Visual Studio 2010 and extend existing tools**.